# how to loop throught Dictionary

Tags: windows

Am building window form application using VS2010.On my login form i collect useid
and password and then click on the login button, if validation is successful direct
users to the main form.
I want to use a Dictionary  to store userid and password read from the DB.
Then close connection. i then compare the inputed values from the textbox againt values:
userd and passward in the dictionary. on sucess direct to main form
here is my code. pls help`

```
string connectionstring =
   "Data Source =localhost;Initial Catalog=HSM;" +
   "User Id=sysad;Password=mypassword";

   SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
   SqlCommand selectcmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from users");
   SqlDataReader reader ;
   Dictionary<string,string> logintest = new Dictionary<string,string>
   try
   {
      connection.Open();
      reader = selectcmd.ExecuteReader();
      while (reader.Read())
      {                
         Mainform main1 = new Mainform();
         this.Hide();
         main1.Show();
      }

      reader.Close();
       `
```

Comment: You need better tags. The appropriate tags for any question are the language(s) that you are using, as well as any software/libraries/frameworks you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in logintest)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

Comment: i need only the userid and password columns stored in the dictionary